# wordpress image isn't displaying where it supposed to

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to create a small wp plugin for my blog, but I've got the following problem.

The post image, isn't displaying in the right spot.

This is the proper HTML

```
<li>

    <div class="projects">

        <ul class="projects sticker">
        <li><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></li>
        <li><p><a href="">details</a></p></li>
        </ul>
        <img src="" />

    </div>

    </li>
```

This is how it's displaying now

```
      <li>

    <div class="projects">

        <ul class="projects sticker">
        <li><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></li>
        <li><p><a href="">details</a></p></li>
        </ul>


    </div>

    </li> 
    <img src="" />
```

Basically i have to put the img tag inside the list and div

Here is my code so far

```
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => '3','category' => $cat_id );
        $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
        foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
         echo '<li>'
     . '<div class="projects">'
     . '<ul class="projects sticker">'
     . '<li>'
     . '<h2>'
     . '<a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look   '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >'
     . $recent["post_title"]
     . '</a>'
     . '</h2>'
     . '</li>'
     . '<li><p><a href="">details</a></p></li>'
     . '</ul>'
     . '<img src="'.the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail').'" />'
     . '</div>'
     . '</a>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra closing `<li>` at the end and the placement of the closing tag of the first `<li>` is improperly nested and `<a href>` opening & closing tag is misplaced as well. Also you could have solved this problem easier—possibly by yourself—if you format the code so humans it can more easily be read. Piling on a stack of instructions on one line like that will only cause confusion:

```
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => '3','category' => $cat_id );
        $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
        foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
         echo '<li>'
         . '<div class="projects">'
         . '<ul class="projects sticker">'
         . '<li>'
         . '<h2>'
         . '<a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look   '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >'
         . $recent["post_title"]
         . '</a>'
         . '</h2>'
         . '</li>'
         . '<li><p><a href="">details</a></p></li>'
         . '</ul>'
         . '<img src="'.the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail').'" />'
         . '</div>'
         . '</a>'
         ;
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it's inside the list, but outside the div.I've looked for other syntax miskates in the html, but I haven't found any.

Comment: Silly me, I've found my mistake. And yes my code is a mess, because i've got this habbit to clean my code when it's already finished. This is something that I'll try to fix. Thank you one more time.

Answer (score 2):

use this code, you have used extra `<li></li>`

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '3','category' => $cat_id );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
     echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . 
          '" title="Look   '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >'  
          .'<div class="projects">' .'<ul class="projects sticker">'       
          .'<li>' .'<h2>' .   $recent["post_title"] .'</h2>' .'</li>' 
          .'<li><p><a href="">details</a></p></li></ul>' 
          .'<img src="'.the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail').'" />'  
          .'</div>' .'</a>'; 
}
```

Comment: @user2013488 seed edited answer,you have closed `h2` after closing `li`

Comment: same result here. The img is inside the list, but outside the div